# sql Like search how pull out data from one table based on search result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
table1 name user             DATA( ID, AGE, NAME,PLACE)
table2 name personalinfo     DATA( ID, EMAIL, COUNTRY, JOB)
```

and both the tables have `UNIQUE ID` for every user.

If I search on first table and got some results how can I pull out the data from 2nd table using the ID results that i got from first search?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include_once("php_files/db_conx.php");
    $sql = "(SELECT id, age FROM user WHERE age LIKE '$searchquery')";
    $user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
    if($count > 0){
        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for $searchquery <hr/>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            $id = $row["id"];
            $age = $row["age"];
            $search_output .= "Item ID: $id - $age<br />";
        } // close while
    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for $searchquery<hr/>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: click on it then search from the other table

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a JOIN or OUTER JOIN to just get it all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after your code

```
foreach($id as $id_table2){
$sql = "(SELECT id, email, country, job FROM personalinfo WHERE id =' $id_table2')";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
   if($count > 0){
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
             print_r($row);
   }
}
```